# normalize a column with deeply nested data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, multidimensional-array, database-normalization, flatten

My problem is about data extracted from a JSON file, with a structure of nested arrays, as follows:

```
data = { "data": [
{
  "insights": {
    "data": [
      {
        "account_id": "10",
        "actions": [
          {
            "action_type": "link",
            "value": "3"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "post",
            "value": "3"
          }
        ],
        "clicks": "3"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "10",
        "actions": [
          {
            "action_type": "save",
            "value": "3"
          }
        ],
        "clicks": "123"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "10",
        "actions": [
          {
            "action_type": "save",
            "value": "1"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "link",
            "value": "11"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "view",
            "value": "10"
          }
        ],
        "clicks": "19"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "10",
        "clicks": "0"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "ON",
        "after": "OFF"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "1"
}]}
```

My goal is to transform this into a table readable on Python through a CSV file.
The output should take this form:

```
    account_id action_type value clicks id before after
     10            link      3    3     1    ON    OFF 
     10            post      3    3     1    ON    OFF
     10            save      3    123   1    ON    OFF
     10            save      1    19    1    ON    OFF 
     10            link      11   19    1    ON    OFF  
     10            view      10   19    1    ON    OFF
     10            Null      Null 0     1    ON    OFF
```

I tried to figure out a solution with the solutions given to the question [Converting a JSON with a nested array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756660/converting-a-json-with-a-nested-array-to-csv).

I also tried json_normalize, but I'm still stuck because of the multiple levels of nested arrays.I used this code :

```
    python        
    df = json_normalize(data['data'],record_path=['insights','data'],meta=['id'])
```

2 problems remain :

- The action column still contains nested values, and as you can see, there's not the same number of action types and values on each row
- The before & after column don't appear in the output. I understand I chose the record path insights > data, and that these 2 columns are in insights > paging, but I don't understand how or if I can select 2 record paths at the same time.

Does anyone see what I'm missing here ?